# Amazon Websocket API Gateway fails to connect with error Unexpected server response: 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-gateway

I have a Websocket API Gateway with a HTTP backend (via vpclink and no proxying) with three routes: default, connect and disconnect.

When I try to connect using wscat it fails with: **Unexpected server response: 500**

The backend service returns 200 so it is the gateway that returns 500.

Looking in CloudWatch I see the following error message:

**Execution failed due to configuration error: No match for output mapping and no default output mapping configured. Endpoint Response Status Code: 200**

What is the reason for this error? Does this mean I have to add an integration response? I thought this was optional.

Answer (score 0):

For $connect route, add integration, for example, `HTTP` that would return a response with status code `200`. Then add `Integration Response` with the following `Response Key` pattern `/2\d\d/` or `$default`